TypeScript Error: Types of property 'width' are incompatible with 'fit-content'
I'm currently working on a React Native project where I'm creating a custom input component that includes an icon alongside a text input field. However, I've encountered an issue with TypeScript when trying to set the width of the component to "fit-content" within my stylesheet.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStyleSheet, useStyles } from 'react-native-unistyles';
import MyTextInput, { TextInputProps } from '../TextInput/TextInput';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

export type IconInputProps = TextInputProps;

const stylesheet = createStyleSheet(theme => ({
    iconInputWrapper: {
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: theme.padding.base,
        paddingVertical: 0,
        gap: theme.gap.base,
        // width: "fit-content",
    },
    icon: {
        color: theme.colors.destructive
    }
}));

export default function IconInput(props: IconInputProps) {
    const { styles } = useStyles(stylesheet);

    return <View style={styles.iconInputWrapper}>
        <MyTextInput {...props} borderWidth={"none"} />
        <Icon name='report' color={styles.icon.color} size={17} />
    </View>;
};

export type TextInputProps = {
    borderWidth?: keyof UnistylesTheme['borderWidth'];
    borderColor?: keyof UnistylesTheme['colors'];
    paddingVertical?: keyof UnistylesTheme['padding'];
    paddingHorizontal?: keyof UnistylesTheme['padding'];
};

The problem arises when I try to uncomment the width: "fit-content" line within the stylesheet. TypeScript throws the following error:
Types of property 'width' are incompatible.
Type '"fit-content"' is not assignable to type 'DimensionValue | { [x: symbol]: DimensionValue | undefined; landscape?: DimensionValue | undefined; portrait?: DimensionValue | undefined; } | undefined'.ts(2345)

I understand that TypeScript is expecting a specific type for the width property, but I'm not sure how to properly handle "fit-content" in this context. Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!

fit-content is for web and does not exists in react-native.
Width expects (percentage) width: "80%" or (dip) width: 50.
If you wanna use all available space use flex:1instead of widthprop.

@MichaelBahl But what if I want to have fit content as the width for a component?
Eg. input text with icon on right, I want to wrap these two elements inside of a View.
How can I make sure that there isn't any extra space on the right side of this icon element? Do I use absolute position for the icon and set it to right? and let the text input take up entire space?

I have created an example:
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInput} defaultValue={'Sample input'} />
        <AntDesign style={styles.icon} name="infocirlceo" size={24} color="black" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.textInputContainerSpace}>
        <TextInput style={styles.textInputSpace} defaultValue={'Sample input'} />
        <AntDesign style={styles.icon} name="infocirlceo" size={24} color="black" />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    padding: 5,
    flex:1
  },
  textInputSpace: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    padding: 5,
  },
  icon: {
    flex:0,
  },
  textInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  textInputContainerSpace: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
});


Thankyou
I was able to mitigate this by using what you did in the orange input
I have a follow up question. What if I want the View (wrapper container) to have an outline when the input is focused and the input should not have any outline on focus...
I am having a bad time defining the outline for react native component with typescript (outline doesn't exist in react native)
I used onFocus and onBlur on the input field by passing them down from the view and have a isFocused state to control the style

Add borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'blue' to styles.textInput
